# What is the ⎋ symbol shown in the menu shortcuts?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, finder

The shortcut shown in the Apple menu for the *Force Quit* menu item is <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⎋</kbd>. (The last character is the Unicode *Broken circle with northwest arrow* character.)

What keys should I use as shortcut of that menu item?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

To be concise: the symbol you're asking about, the circle with the arrow escaping from it (that's the way I remember what it means), is the Apple way of saying 'The ESC Key'.

So the menu item ⌥⌘⎋ 
is <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> pressed simultaneously.

Comment: Wow.. What a cool way to say "a circle with the arrow escaping from it."

Answer (score 40):

The Escape key.

I don't know why Apple use this non-standard symbol, but they always have...

Here is a [full list](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23733) of all of the symbols that Apple use.

Comment: For a full list of Apple key symbols, see here: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/cdb_symbs.html

Comment: "The key is indicated as a circle with an arrow through it (U+238B, ⎋) as defined in ISO 9995." [(wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esc_key) Sounds pretty standard to me.

Comment: I've never seen that symbol in use on a non-Mac system, but maybe I haven't been paying attention...

Comment: My current MBP (early 2011) uses no symbol and reads "esc" on the Escape Key. If it was a standards, I guess Apple is abandoning it now for a wider the-facto standard.

Comment: It's a reasonably logical symbol for Escape, but for some reason I always think it means the power button. :-)

Comment: Perhaps they use "esc" on English-language keyboards, but a symbol on others.  At least they do that for "return" and "shift".

Comment: Not just English-language, but EN-US specifically. EN-UK keyboards also just have the symbols.

Answer (score 11):

As an extension to Ian's answer, here's a list of all the keys:

[Apple Special Key Symbols](http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2005/05/special-key-symbols.html)

As correctly pointed out by Ian, the ⎋ is the Escape key located on the upper left side of your keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a list of all the keyboard icons, terminology, and HTML entities over [here on Meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/keyboard-icons-terminology) . That icon <kbd>⎋</kbd> is the Escape key. You can find it in the very top left-hand corner of your keyboard.

[image: Escape key on a Macbook Pro]

Answer (score 2):

It is the escape key (esc) it is on the top right or left corner of the keyboard